# Concatenating row values to form one row, inline, without use of second table, is it possible?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sqlsrv

Hopefully someone with more knowledge of SQL than me can help here :). I have a result set, that is spreading on two or more rows, but I need it to all be on one row. My question is, without the use of using a temp table (as this is done dynamically inline in PHP), is there a way with SQL to put the values on to the same row when selecting AS?

I've already tried several different techniques and ended up where I am now. Previously I tried different grouping methods, but that wasn't having any of it, resulting in duplicated data or the wrong values. Another attempt was summing the values in to new columns, but that again resulted in incorrect values. The closest I have got is where I am now, but as you will see from the data, the rows are duplicated, where there should only be one row for each term with the corresponding data going horizontally across in each column.

Here is the SQL

```
SELECT
    LineDescription,
    Term,
    SUM(CASE When LineDescription='StandingCharge' Then UnitCharge Else 0 End ) as StandingUnitCharge,
    SUM(CASE When LineDescription='UNIT CHARGE' Then UnitCharge Else 0 End ) as UnitCharge,
    SUM(CASE When LineDescription='DAY UNIT CHARGE' Then UnitCharge Else 0 End ) as DayUnitCharge,
    SUM(CASE When LineDescription='NIGHT UNIT CHARGE' Then UnitCharge Else 0 End ) as NightUnitCharge,
    SUM(CASE When LineDescription='WEEKDAY DAY UNIT CHARGE' Then UnitCharge Else 0 End ) as WeekdayUnitCharge,
    SUM(CASE When LineDescription='EVENING & WEEKEND UNIT CHARGE' Then UnitCharge Else 0 End ) as WeekendUnitCharge,
    SUM(CASE When LineDescription='OFF PEAK UNIT CHARGE' Then UnitCharge Else 0 End ) as OffpeakUnitCharge,
    SUM(CASE When LineDescription='WINTER WEEKDAY PEAK' Then UnitCharge Else 0 End ) as WinterPeakUnitCharge,
    SUM(CASE When LineDescription='WINTER OFF PEAK & SUMMER DAY' Then UnitCharge Else 0 End ) as WinterOffPeakUnitCharge
FROM
    pricebook_bg_elec
WHERE  
ProfileClass='3' AND pes='23' AND SalesType='Acquisition' and StandingCharge='SC' and UnitCharge>0 and 
('2920' between aq_min AND aq_max) AND MeterType='Single Rate' AND 
('2020-07-30' between WindowOpen AND WindowClose) and PaymentMethod='DD'
GROUP BY
    LineDescription,Term
```

Here are the results of the code so far:

```
LineDescription Term    StandingUnitCharge  UnitCharge  DayUnitCharge   NightUnitCharge WeekdayUnitCharge   WeekendUnitCharge   OffpeakUnitCharge   WinterPeakUnitCharge    WinterOffPeakUnitCharge
StandingCharge  12  30.24   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
UNIT CHARGE 12  0   16.59   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
StandingCharge  24  31.18   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
UNIT CHARGE 24  0   16.63   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
StandingCharge  36  43.01   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
UNIT CHARGE 36  0   16.58   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
StandingCharge  48  55.02   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
UNIT CHARGE 48  0   16.01   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

However, as explained above, the desired result is that for each term(12,24,36,48) it would show one row, with the values going horizontally rather than in a vertical fashion.

If this can be done without the use of a temporary table this would be far more preferred, as this data is being pulled in to a datatable scenario via PHP on the fly, which is ideally why it needs to just return the single row values rather than any complications before it gets to PHP. This is why I am having SQL do all the work if I can.

Any and all help fully appreciated, I've been at this for days!

Comment: So what do you want your end results to look like? I can't understand your existing data either, however, that is unlikely to help us as that's the result from your query, not what your actual data looks like. Can you show us what your data looks like before yuor query as well please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `GROUP BY` by removing `LineDescription`:

```
GROUP BY Term
```

And remove `LineDescription` from the `SELECT`.

The `GROUP BY` specifies what rows are in the result set.  If you want one row per value of `Term`, then that should be the only column in the `GROUP BY`.

You cannot select `LineDescription` if you have one row per `Term`, because there are multiple values.  In any case, that information is in the columns.

Comment: This did it, and I can't believe how close but how far away I was. I had tried so many combinations of this, adding in various things and removing various things but never grouped on just 'Term' as I didn't see the logic here, until I just ran it! Thank you @gordon linoff